# Which way of a PHP login is the best way?

Tags: php, sql

I'm coding a PHP script and I need a login. So I want to check the input against a database with username and password. Is the best way to do it by doing a query where I compare if the post data is the same (SQL function 'like') as in the database? After that I count the mysql rows. If it's zero, I deny the login. If it's one, I allow the login.

Is that the common and correct way of doing it or are there better ways? I want to have the best modern way. That's the reason why I'm using HTML5 too.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What do you mean? I know different ways of doing it but I want to use the best method because I dislike to use old deprecated ones.

Comment: You can not use LIKE but WHERE! if hash from input matches sql password field hast setup sessions and so on. If db result are not > 0, then simply do not create sessions and so on, simple. HTML5 has nothing to do with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask You need to show some research and try something so we can correct your code. We're not here to code FOR you.

Comment: @WigglerJtag: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Okay, I'm going to use that kind of check now. I just wasn't sure if it's still a up2date method to do it or if there were better ways. But as you guys told me now, this is the best way. :) Thanks!

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I'm sorry if you guys think I was looking for a finished source code. I was looking for the way I should go. Not for the result. I don't need a code to copy&paste.

Answer (score 0):

Some part of my code. Setting up cookies for the future cookie log-in and also setting attempts in the session to show the captcha if attempts exceeded certain number of logins.
(Hope you can understand it a bit)

Signin call

```
 if($this->check_signin_errors()) {
    if($this->signin($this->user_email, sha1($this->user_pass))) { //$user_pass hashed
      header("Location: /account/");
      exit();
    } else {
      $this->generate_captcha();  
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Signin function

```
  private function signin($user_email, $user_pass) {
    global $con;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, COUNT(id) FROM `accounts` WHERE `user_email` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_email)."' AND `user_pass` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_pass)."' AND access_level >= '0'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if($result['COUNT(id)'] > 0) {
      $_SESSION['account_logged']        = true;
      $_SESSION['user_id']               = $result['id'];
      $_SESSION['user_email']            = $result['user_email'];
      $_SESSION['user_pass']             = $result['user_pass'];
      $_SESSION['access_key']            = $result['access_key'];
      $_SESSION['access_level']          = $result['access_level'];

      $this->set_cookie('cookie_name', '1/'.$_SESSION['user_email'].'/'.$_SESSION['user_pass'], 7776000);

      $_SESSION['attempt'] = 1;
      return true;
    }   
    $_SESSION['account_logged'] = false;
    $_SESSION['attempt'] = $_SESSION['attempt'] + 1; 
    $this->throw_error(5);  
    return false;    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most current approach would be to use the [PHP 5.5 password hashing](https://www.php.net/password_hash) functions.

And because not everyone uses 5.5 yet, there is [a library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) that implements it for earlier PHP versions.

Because hashing passwords uses a dynamic "salt", a random string, generated for each user individually, when logging in you actually need to read the user database to get the current hash, because when you want to compare the login password, you need the hash as second input to the `password_verify()` function.

So actually you try if you find the user in the database (do not use "LIKE" here, this is for searching with placeholders - your user should be able to type his username correctly). If none is found: no login. If two are found: You should add a unique index to the username, otherwise you'll have two users with the same name.

If one entry is found, you read it, compare the hashes, and then allow him further.